Function to take two points and return distance for use in node text
This code draws a triangle and labels each side with its length. Currently it uses a let-in expression to calculate the distance of each side. I'm unsatisfied with this as it would be better as a function taking two points and returning the distance. I tried to replicate the code in the let-in expression within the definition of calculateDistanceAndPrint, but it does not work as intended.
How can I prevent the repetition of code in this example?

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
fixed,
fixed zerofill,
precision=1,}
    \newcommand{\calculateDistanceAndPrint}[2]{%
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\p1}{$({#1}) - ({#2})$ )}
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\distance}{veclen({\x1} - {\y1})}
       \pgfmathparse{\distance/28.45274}
       \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
    }
    \coordinate[label=A] (A) at (0, 1);
    \coordinate[label=B] (B) at (3, 4);
    \coordinate[label=C] (C) at (8, 3);
    \draw let
        \p{AB} = ($ (B) - (A) $),
        \n{AB} = {veclen(\x{AB},\y{AB})},
        \p{AC} = ($ (C) - (A) $),
        \n{AC} = {veclen(\x{AC},\y{AC})},
        \p{BC} = ($ (B) - (C) $),
        \n{BC} = {veclen(\x{BC},\y{BC})}
    in
    (A) -- node[left]{\pgfmathparse{\n{AB}/28.45274}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}
    (B) -- node[left]{\pgfmathparse{\n{BC}/28.45274}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}
    (C) -- node[left]{\pgfmathparse{\n{AC}/28.45274}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}
    (A) ;

    % (A) -- node[left]{\calculateDistanceAndPrint{(A)}{(B)}}
    % (B) -- node[left]{\calculateDistanceAndPrint{(B)}{(C)}}
    % (C) -- node[left]{\calculateDistanceAndPrint{(C)}{(A)}}
    % (A) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

figures/01-triangles.tex|33 error| Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `$' or `$(' (in '$({(A)}) - ({(B)})$ )').
figures/01-triangles.tex|33 error| Undefined control sequence.
figures/01-triangles.tex|33 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
figures/01-triangles.tex|33 error| Argument of \pgfmath@dimen@@ has an extra }.
figures/01-triangles.tex|| Runaway argument?
figures/01-triangles.tex|33 error| Paragraph ended before \pgfmath@dimen@@ was complete.
figures/01-triangles.tex|33 error| Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
figures/01-triangles.tex|34 error| Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `$' or `$(' (in '$({(B)}) - ({(C)})$ )').
figures/01-triangles.tex|34 error| Undefined control sequence.
figures/01-triangles.tex|34 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
figures/01-triangles.tex|34 error| Argument of \pgfmath@dimen@@ has an extra }.
figures/01-triangles.tex|| Runaway argument?
figures/01-triangles.tex|34 error| Paragraph ended before \pgfmath@dimen@@ was complete.
figures/01-triangles.tex|34 error| Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
figures/01-triangles.tex|35 error| Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `$' or `$(' (in '$({(C)}) - ({(A)})$ )').
figures/01-triangles.tex|35 error| Undefined control sequence.
figures/01-triangles.tex|35 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
figures/01-triangles.tex|35 error| Argument of \pgfmath@dimen@@ has an extra }.
figures/01-triangles.tex|| Runaway argument?
figures/01-triangles.tex|35 error| Paragraph ended before \pgfmath@dimen@@ was complete.
figures/01-triangles.tex|35 error| Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
figures/01-triangles.tex|36 error| Undefined control sequence.
figures/01-triangles.tex|36 error| Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
figures/01-triangles.tex|36 error| Missing } inserted.
figures/01-triangles.tex|36 error| Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.
figures/01-triangles.tex|36 error| Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.
figures/01-triangles.tex|36 error| Missing } inserted.
figures/01-triangles.tex|36 error| Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.
figures/01-triangles.tex|37 error| Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
figures/01-triangles.tex|37 error| Improper \prevdepth.
figures/01-triangles.tex|37 error| Missing \endgroup inserted.
figures/01-triangles.tex|37 error| Missing \endgroup inserted.
figures/01-triangles.tex|37 error| Missing \endgroup inserted.
figures/01-triangles.tex|37 error| Missing \endgroup inserted.
figures/01-triangles.tex|37 error| Missing } inserted.
figures/01-triangles.tex|37 error| Missing \endgroup inserted.
figures/01-triangles.tex|37 error| Missing \endgroup inserted.
figures/01-triangles.tex|37 error| Missing \endgroup inserted.
figures/01-triangles.tex|37 error| Missing } inserted.
figures/01-triangles.tex|37 error| Missing \endgroup inserted.
figures/01-triangles.tex|37 error| Missing \endgroup inserted.
figures/01-triangles.tex|37 error| Missing \endgroup inserted.
figures/01-triangles.tex|37 error| Missing \endgroup inserted.
figures/01-triangles.tex|37 error| Missing } inserted.


With the package tkz-elements and tikz or tkz-euclide and a compilation in lualatex

in the class Triangle (section 11 in the doc tkz-elements),


a It’s the length of the side opposite the first vertex
b It’s the length of the side opposite the second verte c It’s the
length of the side opposite the third vertex


we use the lengths in tkz-euclide (ortikz) with \tkzUseLua

we can define a command to lighten the code
 % !TeX TS-program = lualatex
 \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone} 
 \usepackage{tkz-elements} 
 \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \NewDocumentCommand{\mylg}{m}{%
 $\pgfmathprintnumber{\tkzUseLua{T.ABC.#1}}$%
 }
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tkzelements}
   z.A = point: new(0,1)
   z.B = point: new(3,4)
   z.C = point: new(8,3)
   T.ABC = triangle: new (z.A,z.B,z.C)
 \end{tkzelements}
 \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
   fixed,
   fixed zerofill,
   precision=1,}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzGetNodes
   \tkzDrawPolygons(A,B,C)
   \tkzLabelPoints(A,C)
   \tkzLabelPoints[above](B)
   % \tkzLabelSegments[sloped](A,B){$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tkzUseLua{T.ABC.c}}$}
   % \tkzLabelSegments[sloped](A,C){$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tkzUseLua{T.ABC.b}}$}
   % \tkzLabelSegments[sloped](B,C){$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tkzUseLua{T.ABC.a}}$}
   %
   % With a command
   \tkzLabelSegments[sloped](A,B){\mylg{c}}
   \tkzLabelSegments[sloped](A,C){\mylg{b}}
   \tkzLabelSegments[sloped](B,C){\mylg{a}}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}





I didn't know about tkz-elements and tkz-euclid. I have new toys to play with :)
